# Amazon Athena LEFT OUTER JOIN query not working as expected

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to do a left ourter join in Athena and my query looks like the following:

```
SELECT customer.name, orders.price
FROM customer LEFT OUTER JOIN order 
ON customer.id = orders.customer_id 
WHERE price IS NULL;
```

Where each customer could only have one order in the orders table at most and there are customers with no order in the orders table at all. So I am expecting to get some number of records where there is a customer in the customer table with no records in orders table which means when I do `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the price will be NULL. But this query returns 0 every time I run it. I have queries both tables separately and pretty sure there is data in both but not sure why this is returning zero where it works if I remove the `price IS NULL`. I have also tried `price = ''` and `price IN ('')` and none of them works. Has anyone here had a similar experience before? Or is there something wrong with my query that I can not see or identify?

Comment: Can you share the definition of the `orders` table and some sample data?

Comment: prolly wont fix it,  `WHERE orders.price IS NULL;` . but maybe....

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your query is correct. To validate, I created two CTEs that should match up with your `customer` and `orders` table and ran your query against them. When running the query below, it returns a record for customer 3 `Ted Johnson` who did not have an order.

```
WITH customer AS (
SELECT 1 AS id, 'John Doe' AS name
UNION
SELECT 2 AS id, 'Jane Smith' AS name
UNION
SELECT 3 AS id, 'Ted Johnson' AS name
),

orders AS (
SELECT 1 AS customer_id, 20 AS price
UNION
SELECT 2 AS customer_id, 15 AS price
)

SELECT customer.name, orders.price
FROM customer LEFT OUTER JOIN orders
ON customer.id = orders.customer_id
WHERE price IS NULL;
```

I'd suggest running the following queries:

- `COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM customers;`
- `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) FROM orders;`

Based on the results you are seeing, I would expect those counts to match. Perhaps your system is creating a record in the `orders` table whenever a customer is created with a `price` of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can't use `where` for `order table`.

```
SELECT customer.name, order.price
FROM customer LEFT OUTER JOIN order 
ON customer.id = orders.customer_id AND order.price IS NULL;
```

Comment: This query has a different semantics than the original query.. (op is querying non-matched rows, this answer just filters on a column). There is no way this could answer the question.